# Not Able to fetch the input field value from server side when it is set using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dojo, dijit.form

i have an form which is partially build using dojo. Following is the code snippet of the form tag & the submit button

```
<form id="add_info_form" name="add_info_form" action="abcdtest.php" method="POST">

<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" class="rlButton" type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Submit"> Submit </button>
```

have an hidden field inside the form as follows,

```
<input type="hidden"  id="token_id"  name="token_id"  value="" />
```

so on click of submit button am trying to assign value to the hidden field based on certain conditions. have written onclick javascript function which does this functionality & it works ( on inspecting element from browser i can see the value assigned to the hidden field).

But the problem is while am fetching the value using $_POST in a php file am unable to see any value in that field.

Can anybody please help me with it as to how can i set the value of that field from javascript & fetch the same from server side ( using $_POST ) ?

Note: Following is the onSubmit javascript function which assigns value to the field.

```
function createCustomer(){

     document.getElementById("token_id").value = 'testValue';

}
```

Have also tried to set the values using following code,

```
var token = dojo.byId("token");
token.set("value", "testValue");

dojo.setAttr("token", "value", "testValue");
```

both of the above dojo functions (set & setAttr) give error as function not available. Any help over here will help as well.

Comment: Rather than stripping `<` characters, please use the code formatting options. Four spaces in front of a line will turn it into a code block, with `<` marks escaped properly.

Comment: Going to need the PHP side of things what you have tried that is not working. Because if you say the JS is working, then obviously its not that side... but rather what you are doing in PHP. Also, when in doubt always debug by spamming `print_r()` or `var_dump()` functions (your preference). Like `print_r($_POST);` at the top to see whats coming on on POST.

Comment: Randall, Thats pretty simple for php side. You just have to print $_POST array to see what all fields you are getting. I have done that and that is the reason i have asked the question.